# Trying to Import .SQL running WAMP

Tags: mysql

I have seen many tutorials telling me to

```
databaseName < databaseName.sql
```

Running WAMP.  I see where the mysql data folder is.  I put my .sql file in that folder, or in the folder where my database is that I want to import the .sql file into, however no command I run seems to work.

Question: What command do I run from the mysql prompt assuming I am logged in and "using" the correct database?

Comment: just google for `mysqldump` there are plenty of examples.

Comment: I have looked at more than a dozen examples and tutorials.  Thanks for the common sense though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use load date INFILE.

You can use load data local INFILE as well.

I have a 'world' database. hen uploading it (I use a csv), I would use the following.

```
  use world;
  source C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data\world\filename.sql;
```

Sorry I didn't say that I put it here

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data\world

Comment: Appreciate the help.  However I don't want to manually load 70+ tables.  I am looking for a way to import an entire db.

Comment: Sorry at first I did not realise you were using an entire db... 

In that instance, use the following...

change to your database with 

    use yourdb;
then
    source c:\path\to\file\filename.sql;

Comment: I use the db.  Then I type source C:\pathto\file.sql.  It gives Error unkown command '\b'   unknown command '\m'

Comment: That should (does) work. If you are getting an error 22, then you are using quotes in your path? If so don't. If error 2, then your db doesn't know your path and can't open the file 
If need be.. put the file in a root directory (c:\sql for example). 
I f you are getting another error, what is it?

Comment: OMG it worked when I ran the source command while the .sql file was in the root of my C: drive.  I have no idea why.  Thanks so much!  p.s.  I didn't actually use quotes in my command, I was just trying to make sure everyone understood exactly what was displayed.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If and only if your file is a valid database dump (what the file extension ".sql" implies), then you can apply that dump from any location the following way:

1. Start the mysql.exe program *([PATH TO MYSQL BIN DIR]mysql.exe [PARAMETER]*
2. From within mysql.exe use the "source" command like *source [PATH TO sql FILE]databaseName.sql*

Comment: The weird thing was that it didn't work from anywhere except when the .sql file was in the root of my c drive for some reason though.  I kept getting errors.